# File type for .apk extension

Tags: android, apk, file-type

I am building a market for free android apps. I am using CodeIgniter. 
Now, I Couldn't upload .apk files because I don't know the file type.

in Mime.php I've allowed

```
'apk'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
```

but it shows **file format is not supported**.

anyone know the exact fily type for .apk files

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug with the File Upload Class in the _file_mime_type function

Check this link it might help http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/204725/

Answer (score 0):

`apk` is actually zip archive. So you could try `application/zip` or as [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) says `application/vnd.android.package-archive`.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for the file type and found `application/vnd.android.package-archive` on wiki.

I tried, but it doesn't work.

then I print the `$_FILES` and say the file type is `application/octet-stream`, but still not working.

So I just try `allowed_type => '*'` and it works.

but I believe, its not the solution, I am working on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fetching same problem and after print the mime type, it shows `'application/java-archive'`. So I add into `application/config/mimes.php`

```
'apk'   =>  array('application/zip', 'application/java-archive')
```

And finally it's working.